# How to use Keras predict_generator() for segmentation output?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, keras, cnn

Below is the code I'm using for segmentation mask prediction after using `fit_generator(...)` on model named `m` :-

```
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)  

test_generator.reset()

test_generator =test_datagen.flow_from_directory('result/test', class_mode=None,seed=1, color_mode="grayscale",target_size=(256,256),batch_size=1)

results = m.predict_generator(test_generator,steps=17, verbose=1)
```

It runs without any errors but how do I visualise the predicted segmentation masks from `results`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I checked that `m.predict_generator` returns a numpy array so I just plotted it using `plt.imshow()`. Obviously I'd to do some slicing and squeeze on it.

Sorry if it was too trivial

Comment: Would still love to hear others opinions